# How to target "Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms)" project to .net 5.0 in VS2019 (Version 16.8.0)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-5

finally [.NET 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/) is released and i would like to have a "Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms)" project which targets to .NET 5.0. So i created a "Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms)" project.
[image]
But i found it targeted to .NET Standard 2.0
[image]
So i tried to change it to .NET 5.0 by editing the project file
[image]
I rebuilded this solution After i changed ".netstandard2.0" to ".net5.0", but there are errors.
[image]

My vs2019 version
[image]

How can i target the "Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms)" project to .net 5.0?

Comment: We could not change the .net standard to .net directly like above . Here is a similar issue that you can have a refer https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12112

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to use [.net 5 with Xamarin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/), this will be only possible since .net 6:

> We’ve also done much of the early work in 5.0 so that Xamarin
> developers can use the unified .NET platform **when we release .NET 6.0**.
> There is more on .NET unification, later in the post.

So you still have to use .net standard 2.x as shared project.